# How do I need to modify my wgsl compute shader to use it with the node system?

Tags: three.js

I want to create and save a texture with a compute shader. Then I want to load this texture into another shader.

First i wrote a compute shader and fragment shader in wgsl code:

```
//compute shader
@group(0) @binding(0) var outputTexture: texture_storage_2d<rgba8unorm, write>;

@compute 
@workgroup_size(16, 16, 1) 
fn computeTexture(@builtin(global_invocation_id) id: vec3<u32>) {

    var texelCoord: vec2<u32> = id.xy; 
    var uv: vec2<f32> = vec2<f32>(f32(texelCoord.x) / 511.0, f32(texelCoord.y) / 511.0); 
    var color: vec4<f32> = vec4<f32>(uv.x, uv.y, 0.5, 1.0);
     
    textureStore(outputTexture, texelCoord, color); 
}


//fragment shader
@group(0) @binding(0) var inputTexture: texture_2d<f32>;
@group(0) @binding(1) var textureSampler: sampler;

@fragment
fn main(@location(0) uv: vec2<f32>) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    return textureSample(inputTexture, textureSampler, uv);
}
```

I understand the handling of wgsl shaders in connection with the colorNode, because there is a nice example in the three.js WebGPU materials example. I've modified it a bit here:

```
//at the beginning of the script
import {ShaderNode, uniform, storage, attribute, uv, texture} from 'three/nodes';
//-------------------------------

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const uvTexture = textureLoader.load( './textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg' );
const textureNode = texture( uvTexture );


//fragment-like shader
const textureSampleParams{ 
    inputTexture: textureNode, 
    textureSampler: textureNode,
    uv: uv()
}
const getWGSLTextureSample = wgslFn(`
    fn getWGSLTextureSample( 
        inputTexture: texture_2d<f32>, 
        textureSampler: sampler, 
        uv: vec2<f32> 
    ) -> vec4<f32> {

        return textureSample( inputTexture, textureSampler, uv );
    }
`);



const material = new MeshBasicNodeMaterial();
material.colorNode = getWGSLTextureSample(textureSampleParams);
```

The analogies to my pure wgsl fragment shader are clearly recognizable as are the differences. I now want to replace the loaded texture and the textureNode with a compute shader.

From what I see in the WebGPU compute example, I assume that I need the shaderNode and the storage node for my compute shader. But I still have no idea how to use it for my purpose.
Does anyone know more than me and can create a texture with a compute shader, store it and load it into another shader?

In WebGL2, textures must always be rendered out with renderTargets. If I need 6 renderTargets because each shader depends on the result of the previous shader, then that consumes a lot of resources. I want to do this now in WebGPU with 6 compute shaders.

How do I set the workgroup_size in the node system would also be interesting.